# Calculating co occurrence probabilities of search queries

Tags: mathematical-statistics, information-theory, information-retrieval

Hi guys I want to calculate the pointwise mutual information for related search queries on an e-commerce website.

In order to calculate that I need to fist calculate the co occurrence matrix for the search queries.

We say an event is a set of query, user and a product that the user has searched for the query and clicked on the product.

We can say two queries related (co occurring) if there is an event for those queries with the same product.

I have a table of user events as follows:

| query | user_id | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | O | F |
| B | A | F |
| B | B | F |
| B | C | T |

Where A query is the first column for an entry in the table and an attribute of the event.

I am trying to calculate the co occurrence probabilities matrix for this table. So I am starting by counting co occurrence; however I am not sure exactly how to count them.

When I am counting them the numbers are not adding up to the total number of events thus the probability that I am getting is not summing up to 1.

This is what I ended up with:

```
  A B
A 0 3
B 3 0
```

We also see that A on its own occurs 1 time and B 3 times.
However from this table if we sum the A column we don't get 1 and if we sum the B column we dont get 3. Also if we divided all of the columns by the total number of events 4 and sum the results we don't get 1 which is the total of the probability distribution.

I think I am doing it wrong can someone point me to how we can calculate that?

Also it could be that I am defining the co occurence in bad way so correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Your question is difficult to follow because there are too many possible meanings of "query" and "event" one could apply when trying to make sense of it.  Could you please define these terms?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
an event is an entry in the first table. it is when a user searches for a query and clicks on a product.
A query is the first column for an entry in the table (event).
We call two events (entries) related if there is a product that is the same for both of them. I want to calculate the joint probability of those related events